# ASP.Net navbar and gridview error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to make a decent gridview and I finally succeeded. I got everything I needed but after that I decided to check if my navbar was still working. It's sort of working which is very strange. I've ADMIN in my navbar and that doesn't work... All the other refs seem to work. What do I do here? Or should I just make a new admin page and try and move on like that?

Thanks

IMAGES :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using KnowledgeBaseDB.Business;

namespace KnowledgeBase
{
    public partial class afspraken : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Controller _controller = new Controller();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GridLaden();
            }
        }

        protected void GridLaden()
        {
            DataSet dts = new DataSet();
            dts = _controller.getAfspraakRecords();
            GridView1.DataSource = dts;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


    }
}

    <div style="width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
                     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                     <Columns>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AID">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDAfspraak") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Afspraak">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAfspraak" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AfspraakNaam") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOmschrijving" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Omschrijving") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SID">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStrafID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StrafID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Straf">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStrafNaam" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StrafNaam") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>

                     </Columns>
                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                     <FooterStyle BackColor="#D3187F" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D3187F" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
                 </asp:GridView>
             </p>




             </div>
```

[What happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w75yD.png)

[The error itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQpsD.png)

Comment: What it says in english?

Comment: Well it's a school knowledge base and it's dutch : afspraken = rules. I've changed the ID from the gridview I made to AfsprakenGrid but for some reason it didn't get recognised, I quickly changed it back and now it's working again. But I'm still having the error when I'm trying to go to another aspx page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye You can set a block on

```
 dts = _controller.getAfspraakRecords();
```

The Exception is Nullreferenceexception
So I guess the method `getAfspraakRecords()` has some field was null.

Comment: How do I add a block?

Comment: I've checked with the code in Workbench for mysql and there's no null value

Comment: I finded a problem look like your
Mabye You can try it ->
[Link](https://www.ictscripters.com/Thread/22763-c-object-verwijzing-niet-goed/)